# MongoDB find polygon coordinates using single point and radius

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with many polygon coordinates, which represent the different areas.
What my objective is I will send a lat, long and radius in a mongodb query which should return the polygon coordinates that falls within circle area.

Polygon coordinates:

```js
{
    "_id" : "300",
    "name" : "MeKesler",
    "centroid" : [ 
        0, 
        0
    ],
    "type" : "cnbd_id",
    "coords" : [ 
        [ 
            39.8620784017, 
            -86.14614844330004
        ], 
        [ 
            39.8625395793, 
            -86.15442037579999
        ], 
        [ 
            39.8593030353, 
            -86.156373024
        ], 
        [ 
            39.8586935926, 
            -86.15669488909998
        ], 
        [ 
            39.8534225112, 
            -86.15854024890001
        ], 
        [ 
            39.850391456, 
            -86.1589050293
        ], 
        [ 
            39.8511657057, 
            -86.1479830742
        ], 
        [ 
            39.8511986523, 
            -86.14598751070002
        ], 
        [ 
            39.856881704, 
            -86.14605188370001
        ], 
        [ 
            39.8575241063, 
            -86.14605188370001
        ], 
        [ 
            39.8620784017, 
            -86.14614844330004
        ]
    ]
}
```

My query:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "coords" : {
        "$within" : { 
            "$center" : [ 
                [ 39.863110, -86.168456], 
                2/69.1
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: I don't recognize the syntax of your polygon definition. Is it supposed to be geojson? What does it mean "cnbd_id" ?

Comment: This is my whole document and it is a geoJson. "cnbd_id" is one of the  type. "coords" is a array which contains coordinates of all polygons.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that your document is not valid geojson. The valid syntax for your polygon would be

```
{
    "_id": "300",
    "name": "MeKesler",
    "centroid": {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [0, 0]
    },
    "type": "cnbd_id",

    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [39.8620784017, -86.14614844330004],
                [39.8625395793, -86.15442037579999],
                [39.8593030353, -86.156373024],
                [39.8586935926, -86.15669488909998],
                [39.8534225112, -86.15854024890001],
                [39.850391456, -86.1589050293],
                [39.8511657057, -86.1479830742],
                [39.8511986523, -86.14598751070002],
                [39.856881704, -86.14605188370001],
                [39.8575241063, -86.14605188370001],
                [39.8620784017, -86.14614844330004]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Also, you should consider creating a [2dsphere index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/) on the geometry field.

Lastly,  the geo query should use the [$geoWithin](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) operator, and run against the polygon, not against its coordinates.

```
db.collection.find({
    "geometry" : {
        "$geoWithin" : { 
            "$center" : [ 
                [ 39.863110, -86.168456], 
                2/69.1
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: The document that I posted is what I got for development. Thank you for your kind reply. I will try your script and get back to you.

Comment: Perhaps you can still use the data you have if you treat it like legacy coordinate pairs. You still need to build a 2d index (instead of 2dsphere index) on the coord field. See [Geospatial Query Compatibility](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-geospatial/#geospatial-query-compatibility-chart)